# Data set for reasoning?

Tags: resource-request, logic, annotated-data

I am looking data set for reasoning. Basically, more examples like this one:

> 1. I like food.
>   2. Cake is food.
>   Conclusion: I like cake.

Comment: A dataset about your personal preferences? Try asking facebook.

Comment: So you want a list of all the possible logical inferences that humans can make? What for?

Comment: In addition, you will eventually have to formalise your statements in order to avoid duplicates. I like food can be interpreted as 'I like all food' or 'I like only some foods'. I suggest reading up on [propositional logic](https://brilliant.org/wiki/propositional-logic/) and then expressing your examples in terms of this logic.

Comment: @TobyMak, I would like to have something similar to entailment dataset (https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/snli/). So it should match human level of rigor. I would like to take natural language reasoning and convert it to probably first order logic and develop code to let computer draw conclusion. I am interested more in explicit methods vs implicit ones (like neural networks).